# Why is the login screen different?

Tags: login-screen

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10. A couple of weeks back my login screen changed to look like the attached. It flickers a bit. It also seems to have edged an imprint of this screen into my new monitor. I can still see the imprint when Ubuntu's not booted yet. [image: login screen screenshot]

Anyone know how I can change it back to the regular login screen?

Comment: Have you installed any new software recently?

Comment: The monitor being burned in may be off topic, but it is still important, take a look at this: http://lifehacker.com/146469/remove-lcd-image-burn-in

Comment: Ah great to know the monitor may not be permanent - thanks!

Recently installed software - probably. Development stuff all the time, but nothing graphical. I can't place anything special recently or where it might have happened.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you installed another Display Manager somehow (it can happen with a lot of package installations, including other desktop environments). Judging by your background, you installed the default version of Ubuntu. Here's how to get `lightdm` (the default login screen/Display Manager) back:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. A window will come up in the terminal. Use your arrow keys to scroll to the `lightdm` option and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Log out, and you should have the login screen back.

Like [David Cole](https://askubuntu.com/users/431864/david-cole) said, the burn-in you see is most likely screenburn, which is hardware related and can't really be controlled by Ubuntu. Follow his link for more info on that. (I'm also pasting it here in case the comment gets removed for some reason: http://lifehacker.com/146469/remove-lcd-image-burn-in)

Comment: Thanks! `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` just brings me back to a prompt after I enter my sudo password. I've tried installing lightdm with apt again but it says it's already installed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ludo hmm. Try `sudo apt-get purge lightdm` and then `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. Don't log out between these two commands.

Comment: Tried that and the commands ran successfully but didn't change anything. Rebooted afterwards and now boots to a blank screen. Tried to boot to safe graphics mode but same thing. I can ssh to the machine. Any ideas? Looked like the themes were missing when I went into "appearance" before it all broke other than two I didn't recognise (high contrast?) if that's any help.

Time for a reinstall?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you may not have any other choice than a reinstall :/. Try this first though. SSH in and run `sudo apt-get install gdm`. Choose GDM as your display manager when the popup appears. Reboot and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried that but no luck. Did a clean reinstall and all is well now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ludo that's great